# ¿como puedo dejar una linea de espacio?

Tags: c++

Apenas estoy comenzando a programar y quiero saber como dejar una linea de espacio entre mensajes
de salida

uso dev c++ y iostream

ejemplo: al final de mi programa termina con esto

```
printf("\nIngresos por el trimestre: %.2f", ingrTri); 

printf("\nGastos deducibles: %.2f", gastosd);
```

quiero saber:

¿cómo hacer para que haya una linea de espacio entre ambos mensajes?

Answer (score 1):

Ingresa un '\n' al finalizar cada mensaje así:

> printf("\nIngresos por el trimestre: %.2f \n", ingrTri);
>
> printf("\nGastos deducibles: %.2f  \n", gastosd);

Answer (score -1):

Usa otro caracter '\n' y así pasar a la siguiente linea dos veces:

```
   printf("\n\n Gastos");
```

Pero ya que utilizas la librería `iostream`, te recomiendo usar la instrucción `cout` para la salida de texto y `endl`, que también salta a una nueva linea:

```
endl;
endl;
cout << "Gastos";
```

Puedes usarlo todo en una misma linea ya que permite la cascada. Y recuerda usar using para la resolución de alcance. Después de incluir la librería colocas estas instrucciones `using std::cout;` y `using std::endl;`

Comment: Por favor, añade una explicación sobre tu respuesta, el como y porqué debería funacionar. Añado un enlace que puede ayudarte sobre lo que se considera en SO una buena respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer